# Convert html block to image in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, image, laravel-4

I am creating a html code by sending an ajax request.

`Ajax script`

```
$.ajax({
    url: "{{url('/')}}/phpScript", //Server script to process data
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: data, //this is an object with all my required variables
    success: function (html) {
        if (html) {
            $('#someTag').html(html); //change the html of #someTag with new html   
        }
    }

});
```

`PHP Script`:

```
static function createHtml() {
    ob_start(); ?>
        <div class="large-12 medium-12 columns" id="certificate-holder">
            <div class="middle-wrappe">
               <?php //some other code here to create the html ?>
            </div>
            <style>/** some style here**/</style>
        </div>


    <?php return ob_get_clean();
}
```

`This is working fine and I am able to create html and change the html with new html.`

**Is there any way to create the image of that html block, so that I can return the image back and show the image in that #someTag instead of the html.**

I have used `anam/phantommagick` to create image from html, but in this I need to pass the url of page to create image.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I use following technique

https://jsfiddle.net/8ypxW/3/

Jquery Code:

```
$(function() { 
     $("#btnSave").click(function() { 
        html2canvas($("#widget"), {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {
            theCanvas = canvas;
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);

            // Convert and download as image 
            Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas); 
            $("#img-out").append(canvas);
            // Clean up 
            //document.body.removeChild(canvas);
        }
    });
});
```

});

Its works for me. I hope you find your solution.

Comment: [link] http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/examples.html is another option for your purpose.

Comment: This is a good approach :), but I need to do this on server side not on client side because I also need to save that image for use. If you have any idea about that then please help me.

Comment: I guess this plus generates output in base64 encoded form so you can store in DB for future reference. Override behavior of plugin. If you can.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways two generate image from HTML block are:-

**1.Using Jquery:-**

```
html2canvas(document.getElementById('frame')).then(function(canvas) {
       // to view the generated image on the same page
        document.body.appendChild(canvas);

        // to save the image as png file
        Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(canvas);

        // Get base64URL
    canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg').replace('image/jpeg','image/octet-stream');
});
```

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.5.0-beta4/html2canvas.min.js

**2. Using spatie/browsershot package:-**

This package can be installed through Composer.

```
composer require spatie/browsershot
```

In all examples it is assumed that you imported this namespace at the top of your file

```
use Spatie\Browsershot\Browsershot;
```

Here's the easiest way to create an image of a webpage:

```
Browsershot::url('https://example.com')->save($pathToImage);
```

By default the screenshot's type will be a png. (According to Puppeteer's Config) But you can change it to jpeg with quality option.

```
Browsershot::url('https://example.com')
    ->setScreenshotType('jpeg', 100)
    ->save($pathToImage);
```

By default the screenshot's size will match the resolution you use for your desktop. Want another size of screenshot? No problem!

```
Browsershot::url('https://example.com')
    ->windowSize(640, 480)
    ->save($pathToImage);
```

You can take a screenshot of an element matching a selector using select.

```
Browsershot::url('https://example.com')
    ->select('.some-selector')
    ->save($pathToImage);
```

You can take a screenshot of the full length of the page by using fullPage().

```
Browsershot::url('https://example.com')
    ->fullPage()
    ->save($pathToImage);
```

For more options you can use the official documentation:-
https://github.com/spatie/browsershot